# python class rectangle new type

Tags: python, class

I am new to python and I am trying to write class RectangleCollection. class Rectangle is given, and I need to write class RectangleCollection part. 
class RectangleCollection has one list instance variable, rectangles, that should initially refer to an empty list. 
get_same_area_rects takes a number as a parameter and returns a list of all Rectangles from the rectangles list that have that area.

```
class Rectangle:

""" A rectangle with a width and height. """

def __init__(self, w, h):
    """ (Rectangle, number, number)

    Create a new rectangle of width w and height h.

    >>> r = Rectangle(1, 2)
    >>> r.width
    1
    >>> r.height
    2
    """

    self.width = w
    self.height = h

def area(self):
    """ (Rectangle) -> number

    Return the area of this rectangle.
    >>> r = Rectangle(10, 20)
    >>> r.area()
    200
    """

    return self.width * self.height
```

These are what I have done :

```
class RectangleCollection:

    def __init__(self):
    """ (RectangleCollection) -> NoneType

    >>> rc = RectangleCollection()
    >>> rc.rectangles
    []
    """

    self.rectangles = []

    def get_same_area_rects(self, number):

    """
    >>>rc = RectangleCollection()
    >>>r1 = Rectangle(10, 20)
    >>>r2 = Rectangle(15, 20)
   >>> r3 = Rectangle(20, 10)
    >>>rc.rectangles.extend([r1, r2, r3])
    >>>res = rc.get_same_area_rects(200)
    >>>res == [r1, r3]
    True

    """
    self.number = number

    a = self.rectangles.expend(self.area())
    if number == self.rectangles.area():
        return True

    return False
```

but for get_same_area_rects part, I always get False.. 
I have no idea what I did wrong. Please help

i think it is because rc.rectangles gives me r1,r2,r3 addresses, not the areas. I should get [200,300,200] but I get the addresses. I think this is why I always get False..  How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Is `get_same_area_rects` supposed to return a list of rectangles, or a boolean? Also, what's `expend`?

Comment: What is the `expend` method? 4th last line?

Comment: OOOH, that's supposed to be `extend` right?

Comment: I believe so. Typing error?

Comment: opps yes extend I fixed it

Comment: @user3477470, Well? Does it work now?

Comment: no.. still get an error, it says object has no attribute area.

Comment: there is another `expend` in your code. But maybe the whole line should be removed.  The idendation of the  `get_same_area_rects` definition is wrong.

Comment: 1) in your comments of the RectangleCollection class one does not see that there is a method `area` for RectangleCollection . 2)  What do you  expect should happen  if the argument of the `extend` method of a `RectangleCollection` is a number instead of a list of `Rectangle`? 3)  What value should the `extend` method of the `RectangleCollection` return?

Comment: there is area method in Class Rectangle , and I expect the number of area in list.

Answer (score 1):

How about use `filter` function to only take rectangles whose area is `number`

```
def get_same_area_rects(self, number):
    return filter(lambda rect: rect.area() == number, self.rectangles)
```

Comment: A list comprehension would probably be more natural, and would match the desired API. `return [rect for rect in self.rectangle if rect.area() == number]`

Comment: @Blcknght: The result [is the same](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) so both will match the desired API. I think you should post your comment as a different answer especially if you think it is a more natural one.

Answer (score 1):

CSC108 right? This function within class is not asking you to return True of False, it is asking you to call this function to get a list of rectangles that their area is 200

Answer (score 0):

You have a typographic error in your code. It should be:

`extend` not `expend` as follows:

```
a = self.rectangles.extend(self.area())
if number == self.rectangles.extend(self.area()):
    return True
```

Or simply:

```
a = self.rectangles.extend(self.area())
if number == a:
    return True
```

Comment: While that typo does exist, it is not the fundamental problem, and it is likely an artifact of the questioner retyping the code into the question box instead of copy/pasting.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a temporary list and then loop over the rectangles. This is because since we have to return a list which has the same area, we would need to  use the rectangle.area() to compare if they are true or not and then add into the list.

```
def get_same_area_rects(self, number):
    temp_list = []
    for rectangle in self.rectangles:
        if number == rectangle.area():
            temp_list.append(rectangle)
    return temp_list
```

hope it helps :)